# Unreal Engine 4 Basic C++ Code Project giving compile error

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I have been having this a problem when loading up a "Basic C++ Code Project" and have had absolutely no success due to lack of information.

The error is as follows:

```
Running E:/Program Files/Epic Games/UE_4.22/Engine/Binaries/DotNET/UnrealBuildTool.exe Development Win64 -Project="D:/[My-User]/Documents/Code/[Project Root Dir]/[Project]/[Project].uproject" -TargetType=Editor -Progress -NoHotReloadFromIDE
 Creating makefile for [Project]Editor (no existing makefile)
 @progress push 5%
 Parsing headers for [Project]Editor
   Running UnrealHeaderTool "D:\[My-User]\Documents\Code\[Project Root Dir]\[Project]\[Project].uproject" "D:\[My-User]\Documents\Code\[Project Root Dir]\[Project]\Intermediate\Build\Win64\[Project]Editor\Development\[Project]Editor.uhtmanifest" -LogCmds="loginit warning, logexit warning, logdatabase error" -Unattended -WarningsAsErrors -installed
 Reflection code generated for [Project]Editor in 8.2032876 seconds
 @progress pop
 Using Visual Studio 2017 14.16.27023 toolchain (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023) and Windows 10.0.18362.0 SDK (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10).
 ERROR: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
           at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
           at UnrealBuildTool.XGE.ExecuteTaskFile(String TaskFilePath, DataReceivedEventHandler OutputEventHandler, Int32 ActionCount) in D:\Build\++UE4\Sync\Engine\Saved\CsTools\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Executors\XGE.cs:line 493
```

If there is any more information relating to this problem I am happy to provide it.

Comment: Is there any additional information that identifies the file that cannot be found?  It looks like it could be an executable, so do you have Visual Studio 2017 installed?

Comment: Accidentally deleted the following comment: I have both 17 and 19 installed. All the info I know about the file is in the error but I'm fairly sure it is relating to the SDK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It didn't like using UE 4.22.3 for some reason...
Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

There could be something wrong with your installation of visual studio. Check your Visual Studio installer and ensure that the **Game development with C++** workload is ticked. I typically also install the **.NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK and targeting** pack under the individual components list.

In your case it seems to be looking for Visual Studio 2017, so try the steps above with 2017 first.

Comment: This hasn't helped when. Testing with VS2017. I doubt there will be any difference with 19

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after my pc shutdown

after backing up everything I removed all folders except source, content and config than generated virtual studio files using .uproject

problem solved :)

Comment: Could you please provide some reference to support your answer, for example a link from a trusted source?